# MyModel.ProtoModel(fields=custom_fields) Does not work in @EndpointsAliasProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying to do something like the following. Basically `_message_fields_schema` is set to limited properties that doesn't require another RPC calls to be fetched (e.g. key properties referencing other objects). This allow my queries to be faster by avoiding loading all that data. And allow me to do `request_fields=MyModel.get_fields` to get these when I want them returned with the APIs.

However, for an object that has a key reference to MyModel, I thought something like the following should do it but I am seeing a validation error at as see following the code. Any idea if this is a bug or if I might be doing something wrong?

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):

  # More expanded fields.
  get_fields = (...)
  # Default fields.
  _message_fields_schema = (...)


class MyOtherModel(EndpointsModel):

  my_obj_key = ndb.KeyProperty(MyModel)

  @EndpointsAliasProperty(
      property_type=MyModel.ProtoModel(fields=MyModel.get_fields),
      setter=MyObjSet)
  def my_obj(self):
    return self.my_obj_key.get()
```

Error stack trace.

```
Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: ValidationError (Expected type <class '.MyModelProto_property1_property2_property3_property4'> for field myrecord, found <MyModel
 property1: 123
 property2: 'value2'
 property3: u'value3'
 property4: 'value4'> (type <class '.MyModel'>))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1332, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 412, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "third_party/py/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1597, in QueryFromRequestMethod
    next_cursor=next_cursor)
  File "third_party/py/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1275, in ToMessageCollection
    for item in items]
  File "third_party/py/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py", line 1171, in ToMessage
    return proto_model(**proto_args)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 747, in __init__
    setattr(self, name, value)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 926, in __setattr__
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 1559, in __set__
    super(MessageField, self).__set__(message_instance, value)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 1232, in __set__
    self.validate(value)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 1321, in validate
    self.__validate(value, self.validate_element)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 1287, in __validate
    validate_element(value)
  File "google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py", line 1272, in validate_element
    (self.type, name, value, type(value)))
```

Comment: Please improve the code sample you posted so that it can actually be used to produce the stack trace you provided. At this moment it's very difficult for me to even figure out what you're doing inside `(...)`

Comment: Just poking again, in case you are even reading this: please post your code accurately. What is the definition for "_message_fields_schema" or "get_fields"?